# Visual Studio DLL symbol resolution at runtime

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker, runtime

I am trying to make a DLL that runs as a plugin. The plugin depends on some exported symbols by the main binary, but I'd like to enforce symbol-resolution not by the compile-time linker, but rather the run-time linker ( at the time of LoadLibraryA() ).

Can I tell the linker somehow, "don't worry about your unresolved symbols, you can resolve those at runtime."

I would like to be able to recompile different versions of the binary but use a single dll. The name of the binary might change, but the exported symbols should remain constant.

Is there some way to use an "exp" file to get this behavior? Is there some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be possible, I think, using the `.exp` files. See [Working with Import Libraries and Export Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f0z8kac4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).